# highest number in a set in python

Tags: python

```
nums = {3,55,2,1,99,26,11}

high = 0

for i in range(0, N): 
        max1 = 0

        for j in range(len(list1)):     
            if list1[j] > max1:
                max1 = list1[j];

        list1.remove(max1);
        final_list.append(max1) 

print("Highest number is ", high)
```

It is showing me many errors `N` is not define `list1` is not defined after replacing `n` in `nums` 
then also itis showing me type error please solve it

Comment: You are using `N` and `list1` but you didn't set values for them. That's what the errors mean.

Comment: If you want to find highest number in `nums` you could simply use `max(nums)`.

Comment: `max (nums)` ? `sorted(nums)[-1]` ?  `for num in nums: mymax = num if num > mymax else mymax`? so many ways to solve it without  iterating over a range to access the list conversion of your set

Comment: I removed most of the tags you have been using - they are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Comment: You cannot expect your code to access variables that you have not defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
number = set([3,55,2,1,99,26,11])
largest_number = max(number)

print("The largest number is:", largest_number)
```

Comment: It's self-explanatory.